# Walmart API - Public Key Upload failure

Tags: api, walmart-api

One month ago I was able to upload a public key on Walmart.io but now it is not the case anymore, the server is failing giving back a 444 error:

Error: "Error. Please Try Again " + Error: Bad response 444 from server when creating Upload key.

So it is impossible to save the public key and generate a consumer id to use the APIs.

Anyone facing the same problem recently?

Comment: I'm also having issues, except I'm getting a 403 error